# Should cassandra be used in reading before writing scenarios?

Tags: java, cassandra, read-write

[Reading before writing](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/planning/architecturePlanningAntiPatterns_c.html?scroll=archPlanAntiPattern__AntiPatRead) paragraph from cassandra specification tells that read before write has a little impact on cassandra performance. But [storage engine](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_manage_ondisk_c.html) tells that cassandra itself avoid read before write scenarios.

In my case I need to read row "see" on it and dependeing on conditions write it back. So in total cassandra is aproriate solution for such scenarios or not?

Answer (score 8):

Read-before-write is generally considered an anti-pattern in Cassandra due to consistency issues. Performance might suffer too, but more importantly it's never safe to modify data based on previous reads, as those values could have changed meanwhile by another process. The [storage engine](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_manage_ondisk_c.html) page actually explains it pretty well.

What you can do instead is to use CAS operations, or so called "[light weight transactions](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0)". Each CAS update will be based on a condition, e.g. a previous value. This will make sure that updates will only be applied in case the relevant parts of the row haven't changed. Although LWT should work fine for that, scalability and performance will be a lot worse than regular updates.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about your use case that indicates Cassandra would not be a good technology to use, but it depends on your read/write ratio.

If you are going to have a high read/write ratio (i.e. if your conditions are usually false and you rarely need to write back the row), it's important to consider your compaction strategy. Read [when to use levelled compaction from DataStax](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/when-to-use-leveled-compaction) for advice on which compaction strategy to use.

The term "read before write" in your storage engine link is talking about read operations that Cassandra must perform on the disk as part of completing a "write" query from a client. It does not mean your scenario of a client sending in a read request followed by a write request.

If you are going to have a read/write ratio close to 1, you will be able to get much better performance out of Cassandra if you can change your data model to avoid this pattern of executing a read query before a write query.

If after taking into account all your other usage of the same cluster, you are going to have a low read/write ratio (many more writes than reads) then Cassandra is very good at this and you probably don't need to worry.

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account consistency issues. In a highly scalable system as Cassandra is generally used for, and depending on your application, another writer may do the same read, and apply a conflicting write, and only one will win. Other databases have efficient mechanisms to handle this, such as SQL statements that do the read and write internally to the database, or in NOSQL, a CAS operation which will generate a token on the read and require the token to be re-presented. Cassandra's only answer is lightweight transactions which are heavyweight in comparison.